# onmouseover javascript photo gallery

Tags: javascript, html, web, image-gallery

I'm trying to make a photo gallery where the background image of a div element changes to the image whose thumbnail you mouseover (can't use jQuery for this).

Here is my HTML and JS code:

```js
function displayImage(event) {
  event = event || window.event;
  var targetElement = event.target || event.srcElement;

  if (targetElement.tagName == "IMG") {
    document.getElementById("viewer").style.backgroundImage = targetElement.getAttribute("src");
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="viewer">
  <p>Hover over the image to display larger</p>
</div>

<div class="thumbnails" onmouseover="displayImage(event)">
  <div class="thumb-container">
    <img src="img/267400-R1-E003.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

where the `viewer` id is that of the div element I want my photos to appear, and the `onmouseover=displayImage` is called in the div container tag of my image tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to wrap the image src into an `url()` because thats how CSS [background-image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image) works:

```js
function displayImage(event) {
    event = event || window.event;
    var targetElement = event.target || event.srcElement;

    if (targetElement.tagName == "IMG") {
        document.getElementById("viewer").style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + targetElement.getAttribute("src") + ')';
    }
}
```

```css
#viewer {
    height: 200px;
    width: 800px;
}
```

```html
<div id="viewer">
    <p></p>
</div>

<div class="thumbnails" onmouseover="displayImage(event)">
    <div class="thumb-container">
        <img src="http://media.caranddriver.com/images/media/51/dissected-lotus-based-infiniti-emerg-e-sports-car-concept-top-image-photo-451994-s-original.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much, I was staring at that for hours and couldn't figure it out! (if you couldn't tell, I'm quite new to this all!) I have a couple more questions since you are obviously very knowledgable!:

Comment: @IzGao Just ask every one of them as a separate question. There are plenty of helpful guys around here:)

Comment: 1. is the console.log(document.getElementById("viewer")); portion just for the developer's purposes of making sure that it's selecting the correct id? 2. do you know how you would write a onmouseleave function so that it returns to its default value?

Comment: @IzGao 1. Yes, I unintentionally left that there, but removed. 2. Yes, just create a function that uses the line where we set `css.backgroundImage` but set it to the default image's URL. Try to do this and ask a different question if you have problems.

Comment: sorry to bother yet again (and endless thank yous)! i asked another question, not as much luck with this one. got any ideas? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33600808/onmouseleave-returning-background-image-to-default?noredirect=1#comment54977524_33600808

Answer (score 0):

Using [String.toUpperCase](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase) on `targetElement.tagName` might resolve your problem.