# onmouseleave --returning background image to default

Tags: javascript, html, css, image-gallery

[image]I'm trying to return a div's background image back to its default using a onmouseleave method. Here is the HTML and JS:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

function displayImage(event) {
event = event || window.event;
var targetElement = event.target || event.srcElement;

 if (targetElement.tagName == "IMG") {
    console.log(document.getElementById("viewer"));
    document.getElementById("viewer").style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + targetElement.getAttribute("src") + ')';}
    }

function leaveImage(event){
  event = event || window.event;
  var targetElement = event.target || event.srcElement;

  if (targetElement.tagName != "IMG") {
    document.getElementById("viewer").style.backgroundImage: URL();
  }
```

}

where displayImage and leaveImage are called with the methods in the same HTML div tag:

```
<div class="thumbnails" onmouseover="displayImage(event)">
```

In essence, I want to return the "viewer" id'd div element's background image to its default on mouseleave (creating two separate functions). Am I going about it the right way?

Thank you all!

Comment: Are you using `onmouseout` on the .thumbnails divs?

Comment: @AndreasPoulsen just on the div container holding all of the separate img elements

Comment: So it's like `onmouseout="leaveImage()"` on the container? It looks fine to me if that's the case. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: @AndreasPoulsen yep! every time i run it it not only doesn't work, but it messes up my onmouseover method function (displayImage(event)) with the following errors: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
Uncaught ReferenceError: displayImage is not defined 
Uncaught ReferenceError: xdisplayImage is not defined

Comment: It's hard to tell based on this, if you create a plunkr I'm sure I can figure it out.

Comment: thanks @AndreasPoulsen, I got the div background to change, but not to the default background image (just turns the div gray)--any quick idea about setting the document.getElementById("viewer").style.backgroundImage: 'URL()'; back to the background image set in the css file for #viewer?

Comment: try document.getElementById("viewer").removeAttribute("style"), or you can try to set it to something invalid ("", undefined, null etc.) which will make the browser disregard that value and use the one from the css file.

Comment: @AndreasPoulsen YES! that worked perfectly. last question i swear: do you know how to do the same for alt text i.e. remove alt text from onmouseover method function and display default p tag text? Thank you!!!

Comment: Do you mean the alt tag like <p alt="alt text">p tag text</p>?

Comment: @AndreasPoulsen part of the onmouseover displayImage function specifies to display the img alt text instead of the parent div <p> text.   document.getElementById("viewer").innerHTML = targetElement.getAttribute("alt");    how do you revert the text back to the <p> element and not the alt text?

Comment: It sounds like you are replacing the innerHTML and that the original text is gone. You might have to save this text somewhere else, maybe a variable.
Try to post the code of displayImage() and the html of #viewer

Comment: just added these two few lines to the function:   

var altText=targetElement.getAttribute("alt");
document.getElementById("viewer").innerHTML = altText;

var pText=document.getElementsByTagName("p");                
document.getElementById("viewer").innerHTML = pText;      

instead of displaying the text inside the p tag, it's showing: [Object HTML Collection]. here's the HTML: 
<div id="viewer">
    <p>Hover over the image to display larger</p>
  </div>

  <div class="thumbnails" onmouseover="displayImage(event)"> 

i know that's not much to work with, my apologies in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, firstly; it's showing [Object HTML Collection] because you are calling getElementsByTagName, Notice it says Element**s**, so you are getting every single p tag on your website, what you want instead is to get just a single one. The solution could be giving the p tag an ID and then use getElementById, then you would only get the single element.

Second, you need to save the original p tag text somewhere, here is an example saving it in a variable:

HTML:

```
<p id="tip">Hover over the image to display larger</p>
```

Javascript:

```
var originalText; // Notice this is outside the functions
function displayImage(event) {
    event = event || window.event;  
    var targetElement = event.target || event.srcElement;

    originalText = document.getElementById("tip").innerHTML;
    var altText=targetElement.getAttribute("alt");
    document.getElementById("viewer").innerHTML = altText;


     if (targetElement.tagName == "IMG") {
        console.log(document.getElementById("viewer"));
        document.getElementById("viewer").style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + targetElement.getAttribute("src") + ')';
    }
}

function leaveImage(event){
    event = event || window.event;
    var targetElement = event.target || event.srcElement;

    document.getElementById("viewer").innerHTML = originalText; 

    if (targetElement.tagName != "IMG") {
        document.getElementById("viewer").style.backgroundImage= URL();
      }
 }
```

Comment: THANK YOU! It's ALMOST working except for the console log error:  Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null (instead of displaying p text, it's reading 'undefined')

Comment: @IzGao, did you give your p tag an id?

Comment: Could it be because the p element hasn't loaded yet? Do I need to add an onload method?

Comment: In this case it wouldn't matter because it's trying to get the element when the HTML has loaded and you then hover over something in the HTML.

Can you post your code?

Comment: I see it.
When you call `document.getElementById("viewer").innerHTML = originalText;` you delete the p tag because it's replacing everything inside #viewer with the text, then next time it tries to assign originalText to the p tag it doesn't exist.
You can try to do `document.getElementById("tip").innerHTML = originalText;` instead, notice **tip**


You should also put `originalText = document.getElementById("tip").innerHTML;` inside the `if(tagName == "img")` block

Comment: Hmm, it still says: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null 

What do you think, should I just give up? :p

Comment: Never give up! I've tried to recreate your code and made another solution. [Check this out](http://plnkr.co/edit/M4oDfNG45V0iPneBXQpl?p=preview)

I hope you can pull out what you need from that. Basically it's just saving the tip in javascript and not updating it all the time

Comment: Haha, thanks for the encouragement and extra big THANK you for doing that--actually for this assignment I'm not supposed to hard code anything, but don't really see how it can be achieved otherwise! Thanks so much for your help--amazing!!!! :)

Comment: It can be achieved without hardcoding, I'll update later today. Also, this exchange could go much faster if you put all your code on something like plnkr, then we'd know exactly what we're dealing with

Comment: I tried! But didn't see where I could upload the corresponding image files

Comment: don't know what's up with the display/css on this (shouldn't look this way/isn't so on my browser), but here it is!: http://plnkr.co/edit/5GHwcjQ4cLRpzPEBW1Vf?p=preview

Comment: Heres one without the tip hardcoded [http://plnkr.co/edit/mXxyHPXxFdNyIhHan28r?p=preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/mXxyHPXxFdNyIhHan28r?p=preview)

Comment: wow, yes, that is exactly it! thank you so so so much, Andreas! A couple questions if you don't mind!: Do you know why I was running into so many problems with the "Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null?" What about your code made it work? Also more generally, is there something that is critical to make your code work? I'm just wondering why all of my attempts failed miserably! (i.e. declaring originalText outside of all functions--why is this and is it critical?) Thanks again so much, you rock! To say the least!

Comment: No problem, we've all been there.
The problem with `Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null` was because you removed the #tip tag when you called `document.getElementById("viewer").innerHTML`, this will replace everything inside the #viewer tag, and #tip was inside that one so it got removed and then next time you tried to get the innerHTML of the #tip tag it didn't exist and that's why it said null. When you declare a variable outside functions then all functions can read it, if you create/declare it inside a function then you can only access it from that function, this is also called scope.

Comment: aha! yes! global variables, i see i see. well thank you again so much, I really appreciate all your hours of help! :p

Answer (score 0):

I think this line should have an "=" instead of ":":

```
document.getElementById("viewer").style.backgroundImage = URL();
```

Maybe that's the only issue....